# Set SwiftUI variable

Tags: swift, variables, struct, swiftui

I have set my variable `workout_Data`, in a SwiftUI controller:

```
@available(iOS 14, *)
var workout_Data = [
    
    Daily(id: 0, day: "1", workout_In_Min: 0),
    Daily(id: 1, day: "2", workout_In_Min: 0),
    Daily(id: 2, day: "3", workout_In_Min: 0),
    Daily(id: 3, day: "4", workout_In_Min: 0)
]
```

This is `Daily`:

```
@available(iOS 14, *)
struct Daily : Identifiable {
    var id : Int
    var day : String
    var workout_In_Min : CGFloat
}
```

And in a UIKit view controller, I fetch a local json

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    //I parse a Local json
    guard let Json = GetJson.getData() else {
        return
    }
    
    //I make some additional calculations
    let data = ProcessJson.processJSON(decodedJson: Json)
    
    //I print out
    print("1",data.0)
    print("2",data.1)
    print("3",data.2)
    print("4",data.3) //Gives an array of numbers
    print("5",data.4)
}
```

How can I set my `workout_Data` to what is defined at the moment and if the Json is not nil, modify each `workout_In_Min: 0` by values obtained in `data.3`?

Comment: You need to access the `workout_Data` array. What is the relationship between your "SwiftUI controller" and the "UIKit view controller"?

Comment: @aheze they re both independent. I have an other view controller that will display the swiftui controller or the UIKit controller depending on the current iOS version. But I can  get the Json with let Json = GetJson.getData() and also process it with let data = ProcessJson.processJSON(decodedJson: Json) directly from the swiftui view. I don't know how to put those data in workout_Data

Comment: You should have a third class/struct that fetch and decode the json that both your controllers can access, there should be no communication or passing of data between the two controllers

Comment: @joakim danielson I already do. Getjson and processJson are two separate class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this is maybe not the most elegant way to do it, but here is my workaround:

I add this function in SwiftUI view:

```
    func loadJson () -> Bool {
            let json = GetJson.getData()
            if json != nil {
                let j = ProcessJson.processJSON(decodedJson: json!)
      
                let rates = j.4
                
                for (i, _) in workout_Data.enumerated() {
                    workout_Data[i] = Daily(id: i, day: "\(i+1)", workout_In_Min: CGFloat(rates[i]))
                }
            } else {
        
            }
            return true
     }
```

and I call

```
let _ = loadJson()
```

to load the data when I need it

Answer (score 0):

I think you may implement the ObservableObject and ObservedObject in your VC and View

```
class WorkoutViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var workoutData: [Int] = [1,2,3,4]
}

struct SomeView: View {
    // injects in your view when view is inited, must be same instance than in VC
    @ObservedObject var data: WorkoutViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        List(data.workoutData, id: \.self, rowContent: { int in
            Text("\(int)")
        })
    }
}

class VC: UIViewController {
    
    // same as in SomeView
    var workoutModel = WorkoutViewModel()
    
    func processSomeNetworkCall() {
        let processed: [Int] = [5,6,7,8]
        // here is magic
        workoutModel.workoutData.append(contentsOf: processed)
    }
}
```